# Integrating SignalR with Other MVC Processes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have a fairly simple MVC4 web application that accepts HTTP POST requests.  The Controller responsible for the managing the POST request simply parses the form collection and creates an appropriate record in a SQL database table.

I would like to extend my application to provide an administration page that automatically updates each time a new POST is recorded.  For the page architecture for this facility I was planning to use SignalR.  I've used SignalR before, so I am fairly happy with the basic Hub/Client interaction, but what I don't know is what 'plumbing' I can use to get the SignlR Hub to monitor the events on the POST Controller or to put it another way, what the POST Controller needs to do to trigger some kind of event that the SignalR Hub can respond to.

I hope this makes sense, any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you're looking for http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub